# is it possible to change slew rate of pins with icestorm tools for the ice40 devices

Tags: fpga, yosys, ice40

I couldn't find any examples of pcf files setting slew or drive rates. I checked the [tech paper](http://www.latticesemi.com/~/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/TechnicalBriefs/SBTICETechnologyLibrary201504.pdf) that lists the io port primitives, and it seems possible to set the drive, but not the slew.

Comment: Those options are only there for software compatibility with iCE65. The iCE40 devices don't have any actual hardware support for that. The vendor tools simply ignore those options.

Comment: Thanks Clifford.